# run js math function on reload/refresh

Tags: javascript, html

how can I run a javascript function (math calculation) in reload/refresh of the site? Is there a simple way to do that?

The result of the following simple calculation should refresh when a.) the site is refreshed and b.) when any of the math values are changed.

I already tried onload instead of onclick, but that doesn't change anything.

I put up a live website, see here:

http://90.153.112.5:8888/djdp42Bjjr39399nfjjj39xleit832991vnJ39921/live/test.php

and the code (test.php):

```
<?php
require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
$sql = "SELECT * from strategy_sheets";
$faq = $db_handle->runQuery($sql);
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script>

        function showEdit(editableObj) {
            $(editableObj);
        } 

        function saveToDatabase(editableObj,column,id) {
            $(editableObj);
            $.ajax({
                url: "saveedit.php",
                type: "POST",
                data:'column='+column+'&editval='+editableObj.innerHTML+'&id='+id,
                success: function(data){
                    $(editableObj);
                }        
           });
        }

        </script>
   </head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style>}
</style>
<body>
<table class="tbl-qa">

<tr>
    <td >DESCRIPTION:</td>
         <?php
          foreach($faq as $k=>$v) {
          ?>

        <td contenteditable="true" id="Event" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'event','<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $faq[$k]["event"]; ?></td>

        <?php
        }
        ?>

        </table>
<hr>
<table class="tbl-qa">
      <tr>
    <td>VALUE 1:</td>
          <?php
          foreach($faq as $k=>$v) {
          ?>

        <td contenteditable="true" id="Tank" size="2" oninput="output();output2();output3();" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'Tank','<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $faq[$k]["Tank"]; ?></td>

        <?php
        }
        ?> 
    <td>VALUE 2:</td>
          <?php
          foreach($faq as $k=>$v) {
          ?>

        <td contenteditable="true" id="Spritverbrauch" size="2" oninput="output();output3();" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'Spritverbrauch','<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $faq[$k]["Spritverbrauch"]; ?></td>

        <?php
        }
        ?> 
   </tr>
   <tr>
  <p></p>
<td>RESULT: </td>

    <td><a id="StintlangeRd" onload="output();output3();"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">

function output(){

    var value2 = document.getElementById('Tank').textContent;
    var value3 = document.getElementById('Spritverbrauch').textContent;
    document.getElementById('StintlangeRd').innerHTML = (parseFloat(value2) / parseFloat(value3)).toFixed(2);

}

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   setTimeout(function(){
       location.reload();
   },60000);
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Store some ware and get return - like localstorage or other

Comment: thanks @VeluDhanesh. How should that look like?

Comment: that value temporary or permanent

Comment: sorry I'm new to this. Can you maybe post the code?

Comment: Alex local storage used only tempurary. thats why i am asking

Comment: oh sorry. The value is stored in a mysql database, so it's permanent.

Comment: u can use ajax call on then show it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170672/discussion-between-velu-dhanesh-and-alex).